# 500 error when calling webservice through rhosync/rhodes

Tags: service, rhodes

I am trying to call a web service in rhosync application.rb, I see a 500 error response in rhosync console .. and 'server returned an error' in BB simulator .. :(

Some info about my setup -

I have created a rhodes app that connects to a rhosync app when user enters user name and password and clicks on "login".  I am calling this webservice through "authenticate" method of application.rb of the rhosync application ..

```
def authenticate(username,password,session)
    Rho::AsyncHttp.get(:url => 'http://mywebserviceURL',:callback => (url_for :action => :httpget_callback),:callback_param => "" )
end
```

### **UPDATE**

Instead of http:async, I tried consuming a soap based webservice and it worked just fine .. here is code if anyone cones here in search of a sample.. in application.rb of rhosync app

```
  require "soap/rpc/driver"


        class Application < Rhosync::Base
          class << self
           def authenticate(username,password,session)
              driver = SOAP::RPC::Driver.new('http://webserviceurl')
              driver.add_method('authenticate', 'username', 'password')
              ret=driver.authenticate(username,password)
              if ret=="Success" then
            true
              else
                false
              end
            end
        end

        Application.initializer(ROOT_PATH)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can typically find the problem if you crank up your log.  Edit rhoconfig.txt in your app
set these properties -

```
# Rhodes runtime properties
MinSeverity  = 1
LogToOutput = 1
LogCategories = *
ExcludeLogCategories =
```

then try again and watch the terminal output.  Feel free to post the log back and I'll take a look.
You also might want to echo out puts the mywebserviceURL if you're using that as a variable, I trust you just changed that for the post here.  Can you access the webservice if you hit it with a browser?

Comment: I already have these settings in my rhoconfig.txt   .. where should i see the log ?  
Log location in rhoconfig.txt points to 
logserver = 'http://rhologs.heroku.com' ??

Comment: from the commandline after you do your rake run:iphone and the iPhone simulator is opened you should have a rholog-x.x.x.txt file in your directory.  The 'x's be whatever iPhone sdk you have setup - for example : rholog-4.0.2.txt.  Type tail -f rholog-4.0.2.txt and then click around in the simulator - you'll see a bunch of status messages scroll by.  Hopefully you'll see the server 500 message pop up with a little more explanation as to what's happening.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Sorry - just saw you're using the BB simulator - even still - you should have a rholog-something.txt file you can tail to watch the app run.

Answer (score 0):

require "soap/rpc/driver"

```
    class Application < Rhosync::Base
      class << self
       def authenticate(username,password,session)
          driver = SOAP::RPC::Driver.new('http://webserviceurl')
          driver.add_method('authenticate', 'username', 'password')
          ret=driver.authenticate(username,password)
          if ret=="Success" then
        true
          else
            false
          end
        end
    end

    Application.initializer(ROOT_PATH)
```

in this what is done in add_method and authenticate method and where it to be written.